# How to decrypt file that was symmetrically encrypted using GPG?

Tags: security, gpg, pgp

I've created and symmetrically encrypted a file using GPG:

```
touch test.txt && echo 'test' >> test.txt
gpg --output test.txt --symmetric test.txt
```

But now I cannot figure out how to unencrypt it, and surprisingly, I cannot find an example online. Here's what I've tried:

```bsh
$ gpg --decrypt test.txt
gpg: AES encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
```

```bsh
$ gpg --symmetric --decrypt test.txt
gpg: conflicting commands
```

```bsh
$ gpg --passphrase --decrypt test.txt
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: decrypt_message failed: Unknown system error
```

```bsh
$ gpg --decrypt --output test_decrypted.txt test.txt
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: decrypt_message failed: Unknown system error
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you actually look at the decrypted file?  The first version above seems to work for me with a bug in the information text, should say it's a description of the original file.

Answer (score 4):

The correct command is

```
gpg --decrypt test.txt
```

but `gpg` overwrites its output before reading its input so your `test.txt`’s original contents were lost.

You need to encrypt to a different file:

```
gpg --output test.gpg --symmetric test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The usage of the `--symmetric` seems confusingly asymmetric:

- You must use `--symmetric` for encrypting, but then
- Use `--decrypt` for decrypting.

Moreover, you output the result into a different file.

A complete reproducible example (uses batch-mode, prompts nothing):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Some important content" > a.txt
[ -f a.txt.gpg ] && rm a.txt.gpg
[ -f b.txt ] && rm b.txt

echo "secret" | gpg --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --output a.txt.gpg --symmetric a.txt
echo "secret" | gpg --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --output b.txt --decrypt a.txt.gpg

echo "------------------------- a.txt"
cat a.txt

echo "------------------------- b.txt"
cat b.txt

diff a.txt b.txt && echo "Files have the same content"
```